# Animation resource type doesn't exist in resources

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to create a new resource file of type animation inside my android app

I right click on res -> new -> Android resource file

in the following window the animation type is not exist

[image]

what can I do?

Comment: just go to the project repository and create folder manually | src>main>res>"anim"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just leave "Values" as the *Resource type* and set "anim" as the *Directory name*.
It will create automatically an "anim" folder if you don't have one.

Answer (score 17):

I Know it's a old question but may be someone will find this helpful,

You just need to scroll the option window, in the new versions of the Android Studio the option window starts from downwards, the scroll bar is too light in color is often missed.

Comment: What?? OMG! Why does it have to be set this way??

Comment: Not all Heroes wear capes

Comment: Holly molly dude it was exactly my issue !

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder in `res` and name it **"anim"**, remember this is **case senstitive** so don't write **"Anim"**, it will automatically create Animation resource file for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using android studio 4.01. Initially I thought it was a bug. Scroll up. Window was open from bottom.[image: Scroll up in value type option pane]